# how can i get the webkit-column-count value and current page or column Id?

Tags: javascript, android, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing application using webview in android. i am loading a page into webview and splitting multiple columns dynamically using CSS3 webkit property. once user reach the last page/column i have to show the TOC confirmation dialog. can anyone please advice me how to do that ?

```
height:600px;
-webkit-column-width:600px;
-webkit-column-count:auto;
```

Comment: You need to provide the information of your paging method - if you use the native overflow scroll, try to get the value of scrollX

Answer (score 1):

How your TOC confirmation dialog is setup?

One possible solution could be to use the :nth-last-of-type(N) selector to select last page/column element http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthlastoftype.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a small element at the end of the text, and then wait for it to appear on screen. It is easily done using jQuery with [jquery-appear](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/).

[I forked @visualidiot's jsfiddle to create an example using said techniques.](http://jsfiddle.net/VccTF/) Haven't tested it using jQuery Mobile though.

- I put a `<span>` element at the end of the text. The span is floated right to make sure (most of) the last column is shown. In this example, the `<span>` is not empty (and highly visible), but it would be better if it was just empty.
- The javascript `confirm()` dialog screws up the scrolling a bit by locking mouse focus on the scroll slider (tested in Chrome 16 on Windows). Showing a confirm dialog in HTML would not.
- Since `.appear()` works for vertical scrolling as well, this degrades nicely when not having `-webkit-column-*` available (tested using IE9).

Answer (score -1):

Get the total width of your element, and divide it by the width of a single column. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ecp9M/